# Android: possibility to send resultForActivity upon crash

Tags: android, android-intent, crash, onactivityresult

We are using intents to switch from one of our apps to another on request, typically a button that is pressed. That way our apps present themselves as a functional unit to the user. We switch back by means of results we hand back.

Recently we implemented a switch that is *not* triggered by an immediate user interaction, but by an implicit event. When navigating inside one app we use an activity from another app as a drop-in-replacement for some feature in the first app. So the first app sends the user to the second app if it detects that second app is installed.

I realize we have an issue here: if that second app is buggy, crashes, then the first app is broken. Since it switches to the second back again and again without the user being able to alter that behavior. So apparently it makes sense to enable the first app to realize that the second app just crashed. So that it would *not* switch over next time, although that second app is indeed installed.

This does not work out of the box, since the first app never is informed about the crash of the second app. Instead that app crashes, the OS hint comes app ("Unfortunately XY just crshed") and that's it. The flow never returns to the first app, so there is no return value to evaluate or similar.

So my question is: how can I enable the first app to learn about the fact that the second app just crashed?

I thought about registering a global handler for uncaught exceptions in the second app. That handler would have to somehow signal to the first app that it is currently crashing. Either by sending a specific intent itself (sounds ugly) or by handing back a result (is that possible at all?).

Is there a common practice for this? What is it? What other options exist? Or is that question itself obsolete, since I only failed to see how this is meant to be done?

---

UPDATE:

Interesting enough I learend that this actually works *if the crash in that second app is raised not upon startup but much later* ... In that case indeed the first app is in foreground again and is indeed able to detect the crash: the result is "CANCELED" in that case, which is perfectly fine for me.

The the question is reduced to "early crashes" and how this can be handled. Or, the other way round: what is the difference between early and later crashes in that second app?

Answer (score 0):

You technically can't detect that the app crashed, but you can keep something like a "failure counter" in your 1st app. Basically, every time you're about to launch app #2, save a variable in `SharedPreferences`, something like `launchAttempts`. You'll want to increment it every time right before you launch app #2, and then decrement it in your `onActivityResult()` when a result is returned. Then you can set a threshold for how many failed attempts would qualify for "too many", and stop launching app #2

Comment: I just learned that this actually is possible, but only if the crash in the second app happens later, not too early in the app setup. I added an UPDATE to the question.

Comment: Well, you should be setting Result.Cancelled immediately in onCreate() - that's just standard practice. However, you still can't guarantee that the result will be returned to app#1 during a crash. Even if it happens 90% if the time, you'll have a problem the other 10%. My answer makes sure that you do the tracking in your app#1, regardless of what happens in app#2

Comment: Thanks, I get the idea behind that approach. We will keep that in mind. The issue here: as far as I can see there is no way to tell a crash apart from the user simply stopping the app.

Comment: There's definitely no way to tell -- there never is in case of a crash. But again, you can do some leg work in that respect. If you detect that the activity didn't get a RESULT_OK, you can ask a user if "they experienced a problem". So, again, if it really matters to you, it's fairly simple to implement

Comment: Sure, we do have Crashlytics and also Analytics to understand the behavior. The issue is that these apps are used in a business environment where an outage of functionality has severe consequences. Which is why we prefer to disable that second app to keep the first app usable under all circumstances. Which is currently not the case as shown in the question.